# Any system inheritable file I/O dialog in Android?

Tags: java, android, file, file-io

I've used a lot of Android programs, and most of them just create their own folders to save data there. Programs that let user choose path look different from each other.

So I'd like to know if there are any standard dialogs like OpenFileDialog and SaveFileDialog in .NET for Windows?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, unfortunately not. You'll have to make your own.

Comment: That's bad :( I'm still looking for another answers, maybe there is/are?

Comment: Good luck finding one: you can wander through the javadoc at http://developer.android.com/reference/, but I'm pretty sure there isn't a standard "File Open" dialog. If you want to access specific TYPES of files you can use the picker dialogs to access (for example) music media items, or pictures, or contacts, but there is no generic file open/file save.

Comment: Thanks, so I'll have to create the dialog myself.

Comment: Yeah, it is a bit of a pain, but that's the only way forward (which is why you see so many badly designed file browsers).